# In Android 12, is setExpedited an alternative way to execute long running task when app goes to background?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Starting from Android 12, a new restriction is placed on background app when starting foreground service.

> Apps that target Android 12 (API level 31) or higher can't start
> foreground services while running in the background, except for a few
> special cases.

**The following is our use case.**

Before Android 12, when our app goes to background during `onPause(LifecycleOwner owner)`, we will use foreground service, to perform a long running cloud sync task.

---

### Before Android 12

```
public class CloudWorker extends Worker {
    public CloudWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        ...
        setForegroundAsync(foregroundInfo);
        ...
    }
}
```

with such mechanism, we can have a long running task, without being killed by OS.

---

### In Android 12

The recommendation from Google is to use `setExpedited`. (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work)

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
    new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CloudWorkerV31.class)
        .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
        .addTag(CloudWorkerV31.TAG)
        .build();
```

But, from the documentation, it isn't entirely clear on how `setExpedited` behave.

How is using `setExpedited` different from job without `setExpedited`?

```
OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest =
    new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CloudWorkerV31.class)
        .addTag(CloudWorkerV31.TAG)
        .build();
```

1. What is the underlying mechanism of `setExpedited`, make it different from normal job?
2. Can it serve the purpose of executing long running task, when app goes to background?

Or, does it mean, going forward, under normal circumstance, there is no way for background app to launch a long running task?

Comment: Did you solve problem with long running task on android 12+?

Comment: I simply prompt user to turn off battery optimization, if user want to run the long running task when app goes to background. Not ideal, but better than none.

Answer (score 2):

`setExpedited` has absolutely nothing to do with long-running tasks. It just makes the request get processed as soon as possible, instead of waiting for a convenient window, where the OS runs a bunch of tasks at the same time.

You'll need to override the `getForegroundInfo()` class in the Worker to provide a valid notification channel for ongoing tasks (if you don't, your app will crash). And if your Worker thread takes more than something like 10 seconds to run, the OS will display an ongoing notification to tell the user that something is running in the background

Comment: Our plan is to only use `setExpedited` in Android 12 and above as we are still clueless on its actual behavior. In such case, is overriding `getForegroundInfo()` still required?

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll crash on older OS versions, but you should do it for compatibility's sake. See the Caution notes here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#backwards-compat

Comment: Actually, my main concern is, if we were using `setExpedited` in Android 12, is it capable to run long running task (Like more than 10 mins) after app goes to background. It is hard to test out, because it is not documented. So, we aren't sure its behavior in various devices. If not, what is the alternative way? Or, there is no alternative way?

Comment: Again, setExpedited has absolutely nothing to do with how long your task runs. WorkManager in general will let the task run as long as resources allow it, and if it has to be sure down for any reason, it has options to restart that task. And yes, running tasks in work manager is the best way to do any long running work.